# Ajax with callback passed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following code, in a prototype and I would like to pass in the callback functions (successf, failuref) from where the instance of Data is created. This does not seem to get called though, any help appreciated.
It all works fine if defined in the main application obviously and if I use async: false it also works but I would like to do asynchronous...

Callbacks are declared as follows,

```
function bdsuccess( data, textStatus, jQxhr ){                  
                ...                 
};

function bdfailure( jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown ){
                ...
};

//invocation...
var pd = new Data();
pd.getdata('/resolve', 'test', bdsuccess, bdfailure);
```

Prototype is as below...

```
function Data() {
}

Data.prototype.getdata = function(route, req, successf, failuref) { 
    var ps = new Support();
    var bddata = ps.b64enc(req);
    var res;
    $.ajax({
        url: route,                
        type: 'POST',               
        contentType: false,
        async: false,               
        data: {bd: bddata},
        success: successf,
        error: failuref,
    });         
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Your shown function names does not match your description.

Comment: First code excerpt is from main.js whilst second is from data.js. Main has callback handlers defined, creates instance of data object and passes callback handlers to data instance. The handlers aren't reached though that is the problem... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to guess what you want - it seems like you want to set the callbacks in the "constructor" of `Data`

```
function Data(successf, failuref) {
    this.successf = successf;
    this.failuref = failuref;
}

Data.prototype.getdata = function(route, req) { 
    var ps = new Support();
    var bddata = ps.b64enc(req);
    var res;
    $.ajax({
        url: route,                
        type: 'POST',               
        contentType: false,
        async: false,               
        data: {bd: bddata},
        success: this.successf,
        error: this.failuref,
    });         
    return res;
}

function bdsuccess( data, textStatus, jQxhr ){                  
                ...                 
};

function bdfailure( jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown ){
                ...
};

//invocation...
var pd = new Data(bdsuccess, bdfailure);
pd.getdata('/resolve', 'test');
```

Though there's two things I don't like about your original code

```
async: false
```

besides synchronous XHR on the main thread being deprecated, you're using callbacks, so why the `synchronous` call?

```
var res;
......
return res;
```

res is never assigned a value, so, what's the point?

Comment: Thanks cut the code that's why res unassigned, will try what you've suggested. Ultimately I want the success and failure handler outside of the prototype and in the code that instantiate Data. This way I can call with other functions in the to set ui etc in the success callback. Async false was just me testing if it works as prototype implememtation

Comment: See comment to Poul Bok above for further clarity thanks

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this as follows,

in main.js file

```
var pd = new Data(Document);
pd.getdata('/resolve', 'testdata', bdsuccess, bdfailure);

function bdsuccess(data){       
    //success
};  

function bdfailure(error){      
    /failure                   
};
```

in data.js file

```
function Data(type) {
    this.subscribertype = type;
}

Data.prototype.getdata = function(route, req, successf, failuref) {
var doc = this.subscribertype;
var ps = new Support();
var bddata = ps.b64enc(req);    
$.ajax({
            url: route,                 
            type: 'POST',               
            contentType: false,             
            data: {bd: bddata}, 
            success: function( data, textStatus, jQxhr ){                   
                successf.call(doc, data);
            },
            error: function( jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown ){                  
                failuref.call(doc, errorThrown);
            }
        });                 
}
```